# If Many Columns Contains String then enter value for that row

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, str-replace

I have a dataframe called **bd** that looks like that:

The dataframe is this [Link Basedatos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCnZcIwj6YKvXGvF_MHr9rsj6-HlpqUY/view?usp=sharing).

```
   FAC_1                                       FAC_2                     FAC_3 FAC_4 FAC_5 FAC_6 FAC_7 FAC_8 FAC_9 FAC_10 FAC_11
   <chr>                                       <chr>                     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
 1 Substrato de mala calidad (muy meteorizado) "  Naturaleza del suelo ~ "  M~  NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    
 2 Substrato de mala calidad (muy meteorizado) "  Alternancia de rocas ~ "  N~ "  M~ "  M~  NA   NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    
 3 NA                                           NA                        NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    
 4 Substrato de mala calidad (muy meteorizado) "  Alternancia de rocas ~ "  R~ "  O~ "  P~ "  M~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    
 5 Substrato de mala calidad (muy meteorizado) "  Alternancia de rocas ~ "  R~ "  O~ "  N~ "  P~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    
 6 Substrato de mala calidad (muy meteorizado) "  Alternancia de rocas ~ "  R~ "  P~ "  M~  NA   NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    
 7 Substrato de mala calidad (muy meteorizado) "  Alternancia de rocas ~ "  R~ "  N~ "  P~ "  M~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    
 8 Substrato de mala calidad (muy meteorizado) "  Alternancia de rocas ~ "  M~ "  P~ "  M~  NA   NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    
 9 Substrato de mala calidad (muy meteorizado) "  Alternancia de rocas ~ "  R~ "  N~ "  P~ "  M~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    
10 Substrato de mala calidad (muy meteorizado) "  Rocas muy fracturadas~ "  O~ "  N~ "  M~ "  P~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
```

So I need to create 11 new columns, the first column have to search all the values that contains "Substrato" in the eleven FAC_ variables, then replace with "1" if contains the string and "0" if not contains the string; the second column have to search all the values that contains "Alternancia" in the eleven FAC_ variables, then replace with "1" if contains the string and "0" if not contains the string, and the same for all the rest of the columns.

To achieve this my code is the following:

The vector **containers** is the string that I have to find in the dataframe **bd** .

```
vect <- 1:11 #index vector
variables <- paste("FAC", vect, sep = "_") # variables names
containers <- c("Substrato","Alternancia", "Presencia", "fracturadas","desfavorable",
                "Naturaleza", "Material", "Pendiente", "Morfología", "escacez", "Otro") # strings to find

bd$var1 <- character() #empty new column

# Create the first new column with "Substrato" like string:

for (i in 1:length(vect)){
  out <- if_else(grepl(containers[1], bd[ ,i]), "1", "0") 
  bd$var1<- c(var1, out)
}

#For the next columns I changed containers[1] by containers[2],[3],[4],....[11] and var1 by var2,3,4,..11.
```

*But I have a problem in the code that not create the variables, I checked many times but I can not solve the problem*.

> I am going to feel so happy is someone can help me. Thank so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. If you want a single number in var (1 or 0)**

1 = the corresponding string from containers was found at least once in all of the eleven FAC_ variables in the same row

Using the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
for (i in seq_along(containers)){
  bd <- bd %>%
    mutate(!!sym(paste0("var",i)) := apply(bd[,1:11], 1, function(vec){str_detect(vec, containers[i]) %>% any(na.rm=T) %>% as.numeric}))
}
```

**Output**

```
> bd
# A tibble: 35,279 x 22
   FAC_1    FAC_2    FAC_3    FAC_4    FAC_5   FAC_6  FAC_7 FAC_8 FAC_9 FAC_10 FAC_11  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8  var9 var10 var11
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Substra~ Natural~ "Morfol~  NA       NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 2 Substra~ Alterna~ "Natura~ "Materi~ "Morfo~  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
 3 NA       NA        NA       NA       NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 4 Substra~ Alterna~ "Rocas ~ "Orient~ "Pendi~ "Morf~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
 5 Substra~ Alterna~ "Rocas ~ "Orient~ "Natur~ "Pend~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
 6 Substra~ Alterna~ "Rocas ~ "Pendie~ "Morfo~  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         1     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 7 Substra~ Alterna~ "Rocas ~ "Natura~ "Pendi~ "Morf~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         1     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
 8 Substra~ Alterna~ "Materi~ "Pendie~ "Morfo~  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
 9 Substra~ Alterna~ "Rocas ~ "Natura~ "Pendi~ "Morf~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         1     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
10 Substra~ Rocas m~ "Orient~ "Natura~ "Mater~ "Pend~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
# ... with 35,269 more rows
```

**2. If you want a 1 or 0 for each of the eleven FAC_, and this in every var**

I put the 1 and 0 in a list, so var1 is a vector of lists. Each element is a list with 11 numbers.

```
for (i in seq_along(containers)){
  bd <- bd %>%
    mutate(!!sym(paste0("var",i)) := apply(bd[,1:11], 1, function(vec){map(vec, ~grepl(containers[i], .) %>% as.numeric)}))
}
```

The calculation takes a bit of time but I do find

**Output**

```
> bd
# A tibble: 35,279 x 22
   FAC_1   FAC_2   FAC_3   FAC_4   FAC_5   FAC_6  FAC_7 FAC_8 FAC_9 FAC_10 FAC_11 var1   var2   var3   var4   var5  var6  var7  var8  var9  var10 var11
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl>  <list> <list> <list> <list> <lis> <lis> <lis> <lis> <lis> <lis> <lis>
 1 Substr~ Natura~ "Morfo~  NA      NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     <name~ <name~ <name~ <name~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~
 2 Substr~ Altern~ "Natur~ "Mater~ "Morfo~  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     <name~ <name~ <name~ <name~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~
 3 NA      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     <name~ <name~ <name~ <name~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~
 4 Substr~ Altern~ "Rocas~ "Orien~ "Pendi~ "Morf~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     <name~ <name~ <name~ <name~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~
 5 Substr~ Altern~ "Rocas~ "Orien~ "Natur~ "Pend~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     <name~ <name~ <name~ <name~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~
 6 Substr~ Altern~ "Rocas~ "Pendi~ "Morfo~  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     <name~ <name~ <name~ <name~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~
 7 Substr~ Altern~ "Rocas~ "Natur~ "Pendi~ "Morf~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     <name~ <name~ <name~ <name~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~
 8 Substr~ Altern~ "Mater~ "Pendi~ "Morfo~  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     <name~ <name~ <name~ <name~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~
 9 Substr~ Altern~ "Rocas~ "Natur~ "Pendi~ "Morf~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     <name~ <name~ <name~ <name~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~
10 Substr~ Rocas ~ "Orien~ "Natur~ "Mater~ "Pend~ NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     <name~ <name~ <name~ <name~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~ <nam~
# ... with 35,269 more rows
> bd$var1[1]
[[1]]
[[1]]$FAC_1
[1] 1

[[1]]$FAC_2
[1] 0

[[1]]$FAC_3
[1] 0

[[1]]$FAC_4
[1] 0

[[1]]$FAC_5
[1] 0

[[1]]$FAC_6
[1] 0

[[1]]$FAC_7
[1] 0

[[1]]$FAC_8
[1] 0

[[1]]$FAC_9
[1] 0

[[1]]$FAC_10
[1] 0

[[1]]$FAC_11
[1] 0
```

---

**Edit: if you want the whole string where we found the word in the cell**

If you are certain each word can only appear once in the row, you can do

```
for (i in seq_along(containers)){
  bd <- bd %>%
    mutate(!!sym(paste0("var",i)) := apply(bd[,1:11], 1, function(vec){ifelse(str_detect(vec, containers[i]) %>% any(na.rm=T),
                                                                              str_subset(vec, containers[i]),
                                                                              NA)}))
}
```

with the value of the cells filled if the word was found, `NA` if the word was not found. If you want to change the value when the word was not found, modify `NA` in the ifelse function, for example with `"Not found"`.

Comment: thank so much for your help. But I was checking the result and in the **newcol6** that is the column that have to contain **Naturaleza** from the FAC_ variables is fill with 0 but that cells in many columns have **Naturaleza** like string. See the following [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gscP3MPtpIUJTfitFAQ6oIg5-3jSoAdT/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Yes, I made some mistakes before. I have updated my solution with 2 methods, try it and tell me.

Comment: The two methods works properly. I feel so happy, and thank so much for help me :D!!!

Comment: No problem, it was interesting to solve. Please tag the post as accepted answer if it solves your problem =)

Comment: Last but not least question: if instead of "1" I have to copy the cell value, how much I have to modified the code. Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: See my edit. I use str_subset instead, with an ifelse condition to catch the cases where the word cannot be found.